# unable to update the variable value inside a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am unable to get the updated value from the function. The code is similar to Javascript and ajax.

```js
var created_ByRegion = g_form.getValue('u_region');
var g_number = g_form.getValue("u_number");
var response = '';
var ga = new GlideAjax('getRegionUsers');
ga.addParam('sysparm_name', "getUsers");
ga.addParam('sysparm_region', created_ByRegion); //Onchange field is reference field to sys_user table

ga.getXMLAnswer(function(answer) {
  var response = answer;
});
alert(response);
```

Comment: The callback function you provide to `getXMLAnswer()` is asynchronous, therefore `alert(response)` has executed long before `var response = answer` has been invoked. To fix this, ***all*** logic dependant on the `answer` argument must be within, or invoked from, the callback you pass to `getXMLAnswer()`. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: Also `var` is functional scoped, so even without it been `async` you wound't be able to access `response`